# HTML and CSS basics.. google font not working?

Tags: html, css, fonts, codepen

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have...

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC" 
rel="stylesheet"type="text/css">


h1{ font-family: 'Spectral SC', serif;
}

.green-text{
color:rgb(0,255,0);
}

<h1 class=" text-center green-text">"Don't let anyone define you. You define 
yourself."</h1>
```

I am using codePen and it told me I don't have to include 'style' because they have it there imported already. My font isn't working, what am I doing wrong?? thank you!

```
 Heres a link to a screenshot of my window...


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQj42.png
```

Comment: Your code works fine, [**even in CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/OQjQNr). It correctly applies the font. Could you please share your CodePen showcasing this error in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry for the awkward link, but I just added it to my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're writing `HTML` in the `CSS` section of CodePen, which confuses it.

Simply shift your `<link>` reference to the Google Font to the `HTML` section, as can be seen in the **[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/OQjQNr)** I already shared.

This can also be seen in the following StackSnippet:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Spectral SC', serif;
}

.green-text {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<h1 class=" text-center green-text">"Don't let anyone define you. You define yourself."</h1>
```

Note that when you move to using your own site, you'll either need to add another `<link>` tag pointing to your own CSS file, or write your CSS within `<style>` tags.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Place the **link** tag in the html file. According to the screenshot, you have placed it in the **css** file.